# Trying to understand this CNN Model - PyTorch

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I am trying to understand this model, by building it from scratch.

I am trying to start with just one layer, but I am getting error stating output of layer1 is not the expected input type for fc1.

`RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (64x197136 and 2704x2704)`

I am not 100% sure if I can do this with 1 layer, but I am trying to learn by playing around with it.

code(Which I am trying to play around with):

```
# Craete a neural network from pytorch
# https://www.kaggle.com/code/reukki/pytorch-cnn-tutorial-with-cats-and-dogs
class Cnn(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Cnn,self).__init__()
        
        self.layer1 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=1, out_channels=16, kernel_size=3, padding=0, stride=2),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(num_features=16),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2)
        )

        
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(3*3*16,10)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(0.5)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(10,2)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        
        
    def forward(self,x):
        out = self.layer1(x)
        out = out.view(out.size(0),-1)
        out = self.fc1(out)
        out = self.relu(out)
        out = self.fc2(out)
        return out
```

I am also unsure what `out.view(out.size(0),-1)` does.

Would be great if anyone can help me understand better. Looking forward to some

[Update]

Kaggle Notebook link:- https://www.kaggle.com/austonpramodh/cats-dogs-cnn-learning

Answer (score 0):

out.view(out.size(0),-1) flattens your output dimension to 1-dimension(1d) according to (whatever_number_fits_it_perfectly_for_1d), for example if out.size(0) is 512x512, this command will make it to 262144 and remove the 2nd dimension. You can also say it as 262144x1.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the answer from one of my friend, Thanks to Vihari.

```
class Cnn(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Cnn,self).__init__()
        
        self.layer1 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=1, out_channels=16, kernel_size=3, padding=0, stride=2),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(num_features=16),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2)
        )

        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(55 * 55 * 16, 2)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        
        
    def forward(self,x):
        out = self.layer1(x)
        # print("****Layer Size***")
        # # 55*55*16
        # print(out.size(1))
        # print("****Layer Size***")
        out = self.relu(out)
        out = out.view(out.size(0), out.size(1)*out.size(2)* out.size(3))
        # print("****View Size***")
        # print(out.size()[-1], out.size(1))
        # print("****View Size***")
        out = self.fc1(out)
        return out
```

Also, Thanks for the out.view explanation @Pranav.